# FIlter in controller with multiple values

Tags: angularjs

I have 3 switches (checkboxes, they return true or false) to filter in a list.

The list:

```
vm.products = Product.query();
```

In my controller, i want to filter vm.products, everytime one of the switchboxes/checkboxes get changed.

All i got so far, is a none working, filter argument:

```
vm.products = $filter('filter')('id', 1);
```

The parameter 'filter' - sems like its pointing at a directive? Do i have to do that? And what would be the best way of making a dynamic filter function/builder, when there is multiple values to check on?

Comment: read the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: Already did, they did not help me. Therefore my question here.

Comment: I got this working:

        vm.filterTypeUpdated = function ($event, typeId) {
            console.log(typeId + ': ' + $event);
            vm.products = $filter('filter')(vm.products, { productTypeId: typeId })
        }

But this only supports one value being set. How could i build a filter query?

Comment: do you have a plunger where i can play in?

Comment: No plunker i afraid :(

Answer (score 0):

I found a way using a custom filter;

```
.filter("myFilter", function(){

        return function(products, productTypes){

            var selectedProducts = [];
            for (i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
                if (productTypes.indexOf(products[i].productTypeId.toString()) > -1) {
                    selectedProducts.push(incidents[i]);
                }
            }

            return selectedProducts;
        };

    })
```

I then use this in my controller to call the filter function;

```
vm.filterTypeUpdated = function ($event, typeId) {
    var productTypesId = "";
    if (vm.filterType1)
        productTypesId += "1,";
    if (vm.filterType2)
        productTypesId += "2,";
    if (vm.filterType3)
        productTypesId += "3,";

    vm.productsRoot = $filter('myFilter')(vm.products, productTypesId);
}
```

I don't feel like this is the cleanest way of doing it, but it works. If there are any inputs on optimizing this, i am all ears :-)